# Left outer join Microsoft excel query Issue

Tags: sql, excel, join

I have the following excel tables:

Table :a

```
week    Item    qty 

wk1      a      1   
wk2      b      1  
wk3      b      2
```

and table: w

```
week    Item    sales 
wk1 a   11 
wk2 b   22 
wk1 b   33 
wk2 b   4 
wk3 b   5
```

I would like to apply the LEFT JOIN in order to  return all rows from the left table (w), with the matching rows in the right table (a) according the following query

```
SELECT `a$`.week, `a$`.Item, `a$`.qty, `w$`.sales
FROM {oj `C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.xlsx`.`w$` `w$`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.xlsx`.`a$` `a$`
    ON `a$`.week = `w$`.week}
WHERE `w$`.Item = `a$`.Item
```

However I am not getting the desired result

```
week    Item    qty sales
wk1 a   1   11
wk2 b   1   4
wk2 b   1   22
wk3 b   2   5
```

as the following row is missing

```
wk1 b       33
```

Any ideas ? or suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance 
Kostas

Comment: Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You're missing `wk1 b` because it doesn't exist in `Table a`. Remove the `Where` clause and add that comparing of the `Item` in the `Join` statement

Answer (score 0):

You actually did inner join not outer join.
Because you used

```
WHERE w$.Item = a$.Item
```

First, you've got records including sales is 33.

Second, you've removed record sales is 33 by this condition.

So, removing this condition will be no problem.

Comment: Columns are crunched... That's actually the Sales of 33.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I don't understand what you meaning. But your answer and my answer has same result. Because w table has all rows which exist in a table. And he asked why result table not including Sales of 33, so I answerd why he lose it.

Comment: Yes, I thought you meant 33 was the Item number. ;-)

Comment: @WEI_DBA Oh, I understand my mistake now. I corrected item to sales, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a where clause that contradicts your expected result. Remove the where clause  and you will get the result you expected.